# How to bring out the tray at the bottom in Ubuntu Gnome 13.10

Tags: gnome, 13.10, gui

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 13.10. I accidentally moved the cursor somewhere near the right-bottom part of the screen and it brought out this pane -

[image]

I want to know how do you get to that pane. Are there any keyboard shortcuts for this?

Comment: You can `Super+M` to bring this tray.

Comment: I discovered moving the cursor to the bottom with pressure also invokes this tray.